# Get child records in suitescript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a customer which is parents and there might be several subcustomers for this customer . This Subcustomer is a child subtab under a parent subtab(Relationships). How do i fetch or get all the subcustomers for a parent customer. I need to update some values of subcustomer based on parent customers field value.

Answer (score 2):

to get the sub customers in suitescripts you can use `parent` filter. For Example the below search:

```
var subCutsomersResults = nlapiSearchRecord('customer', null, ['parent', 'anyof', PARENT_CUSTOMER_ID], YOUR_SEARCH_COLUMNS_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Thanks, i created a saved search and used `nlapiSearchRecord` and got an array of subcustomers. But when i looped the array i did not know how  to update the addr1,addr2 values . Also i tried your code mentioned above `11  var subCutsomersResults = nlapiSearchRecord('customer', null, ['parent', 'anyof', 930], billaddr1,billaddr2,billcity);` but there are no values in my `nlobjsearchresult` column. I need to change the address field values of child(sudcust).

Comment: to get the searchresults, please use `nlobjSearchcolumn` and field names as in the record browser https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2015_1/script/record/customer.html . eg: `[new nlobjSearchColumn('address1'), new nlbojSearchColumn('address2')`]

Comment: Also, to edit address details, I suggest you to see the help topic `Sample Scripts for Address Subrecords`

Comment: Thanks , But i tried all possible way. `var subCutsomersResults = nlapiSearchRecord('customer', null, ['parent', 'anyof', 930],new nlobjSearchColumn(addr1));` . 'addr1' is the subcustomer's address field. I gave it with quotes too. it throws error `ReferenceError: "addr1" is not defined`.

Comment: try `"addr1"` i.e. with quotes, should work. sometimes some keyboard or copy-paste it takes the rounded quotes not the developer quotes